# Are there any efficient methods, shortcuts, theorems, or hacks to determine whether the graph is chordal for cases where it's sparse?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm working with a graph that has 20 vertices or nodes. This graph is relatively sparse, with an average of only 2 edges per node (or less). Are there any efficient methods, shortcuts, theorems, or hacks to determine whether the graph is chordal for cases where it's sparse (e.g., when the number of edges is much less than the number of node)?

More specifically, my problem is the following:

I have an algorthim that starts at an empty graph G0 (see above picture). The rules is this:

1. For every non zero entries in the mask matrix m0,  you have to check if the graph is chordal at these entries. e.g. entries (a,b) is zero and so. you have to check if adding an undirected edge between node a and b will be chordal. Thus, you have to check if the matrix m0(a,b) is chordal. You also have to do the same for the other non zero entries(e.g. check if m0(a,c), m0(a,d) etc are chordal).

2.Every zero entries in the mask matrix (e.g m0) are the possible ways (e.g. actions) you can add ONE undirected edges to G0.  At state G0, you have to choose only one of these possible actions to traverse to the next graph e.g. G1.
For example, m0[a,b]=0. This zero entry at [a,b]represents adding undirected edge between node a and node b in G0. Similarly, m0(a,c) represents adding undirected edge between node a and c in G0 etc.
My problem is for each graph Gi,  I have to check whether m0 at every non zero entries is chordal. This gets computationally expensive when the mask matrix is large is a 2500x2500 matrix, and I have to do this for many matrices. So i am trying to find a hack or theorem so that i don't have to check if a graph is chordal at every non zero entries of a mask matrix.
[image]

Comment: The algorithm on Wikipedia is linear-time; you don't need shortcuts or hacks!

Comment: I need to to call the function a few millions times and so the computational time adds up. More specifically, if it takes 0.049sec to compute one graph, then it will take 13.6hrs to compute a million of these graphs. This would take too long

Comment: so i am trying to find some hacks or theorems where i can reduce the number of checking whether a graph is chordal.

Comment: You might have to explain more about what you're doing (and in what context).

Comment: ok i've added more detail at the top along with some images.
I know one of the hacks is i won't have to check if a graph is chordal is the adjacency matrix has less than 4 edges. I was wondering if there are more

Comment: What do you mean by a graph being chordal "at" some entries? (But it sure looks like we can avoid doing a long computation to re-check a graph for being chordal, when we just add one edge to a graph.) Also, is your ultimate goal to just find a way to get from the empty graph to a complete graph while having a chordal graph at each step?

Comment: "by a graph being chordal "at" some entries", I mean the following: For every zero entries in the mask matrix mo (see image above), m1 etc, I would assign a one. For example, m0[a,b]=0 and so I would assign this entry to a one  (m0[a,b]=1). I would check if this mask matrix m0 with entries [a,b]=1 is chordal. I would do the same for the other zero entries e.g. assign m0[a,b]=1 and check if this new matrix is chordal. assign m0[a,c]=1 and check if this new matrix is chordal

Comment: Given the mask matrix (m) is sparse, my ultimate goal to just find a way to reduce the number of times i have to check whehter the graph is chordal when i assign a 1 to [i,j] entries where m[i,j]=0

Comment: "But it sure looks like we can avoid doing a long computation to re-check a graph for being chordal, when we just add one edge to a graph." 

If you have any ideas or suggestions, I would love to hear it

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematica*:

```
gr = RandomGraph[{20, 40}]
```

[image]

```
Timing[ResourceFunction["ChordalGraphQ"][gr]]
```

(* {0.049059, False} *)

For the case you desire the time was $0.002437$ s, so a million graphs in less than an hour.

0.049 seconds should be fast enough for you!

Comment: thanks, but that would be too slow. Please see my above comments

Comment: Note that this graph has $20$ vertices and $40$ edges, for an average degree of around $4$. If we go down to average degree $2$, the algorithm becomes much faster (about 60x faster on my laptop). I would try this approach out before dismissing it.

Comment: Misha is correct.  I redid the simulation for the proper case and found $0.002437$ s, so a million cases in less than an hour.  I trust that is acceptable.

Comment: Well, I acutally need to compute more closer to a 30 million times and so 0.002437 won't be fast enough

Comment: Then you likely can't do it and should give up.  By the way, perhaps you'll calculate whether there *are* 30 million different such graphs.

Comment: well there are alternative ways, maybe just not this way. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 1):

If the input graph is sparse, we can often simplify the graph considerably while testing to see if it's chordal. Specifically:

1. If $v$ is a vertex of degree $1$, then $G$ is chordal if and only if $G-v$ is chordal. (This follows from the definition, since $v$ cannot be part of any cycles, so it suffices to check the cycles of $G-v$.)
2. If $v$ is a vertex of degree $2$, and its neighbors $x$ and $y$ are adjacent, then $G$ is chordal if and only if $G-v$ is chordal. (Here, every cycle of length $\ge 4$ containing $v$ has the chord $xy$.)
3. If $v$ is a vertex of degree $2$, and its neighbors $x$ and $y$ are not adjacent but have another common neighbor $z$, then $G$ is not chordal. (The cycles $v,x,z,y,v$ is a chordless cycle.)
4. If $v$ is a vertex of degree $2$, and its neighbors $x$ and $y$ are not adjacent and have no other common neighbor, then $G$ is chordal if and only if the graph $H$ obtained from $G-v$ by adding the edge $xy$ is chordal. (Here, every long cycle in $G$ containing $v$ corresponds to a long cycle in $H$ containing $x$ and $y$.)

This (1) lets us look at a considerably smaller graph, and (2) lets us take many shortcuts in checking what happens when a new edge is added to a graph. Specifically, if one of the endpoints of the new edge has degree $1$, this does not change chordality, and in some cases we can get an answer right away if one of the endpoints has degree $2$.

---

Specifically for the application where we will be adding edges to a graph one at a time, and want to see how the chordality changes, it may be worthwhile to keep track of the [block-cut tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component#Block-cut_tree) of the graph. All cycles of the graph are contained within a single block, so the entire graph is chordal if and only if each block is chordal.

When a new edge is added:

- if its endpoints lie in the same block, we only need to determine whether that block is chordal.
- If its endpoints lie in different blocks *and* in different connected components, then together they form a new (necessarily chordal) block.
- If its endpoints lie in different blocks but in the same connected component, then several blocks (the blocks encountered along an arbitrarily-chosen path between the endpoints in the old graph) become a single block, and we need to test that block for being chordal.

---

Not all of these tricks might be worthwhile depending on implementation details. I would start from a baseline of a general-purpose algorithm for testing chordality, see how it performs, and then try changes from there to see if they improve the behavior.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate the incredibly useful information you've provided

Comment: Hi Misha, I would like to get some clarifications for property 4 above. More specifically, I am a bit confused with this sentence: "  is chordal if and only if the graph  obtained from − by adding the edge  is chordal". by adding xy, do you mean adding x--y to graph G-v?

Comment: In property 2, you wrote: "If  is a vertex of degree , and its neighbors  and  are adjacent"

is the sentence implying all neighbours of  have to be adjacent, or only some?

Comment: For the first question, yes: we're deleting $v$, and then adding the edge $xy$. For the second question, since $v$ is a vertex of degree 2, then it has exactly 2 neighbors, so there's no way that "only some" of its neighbors are adjacent - it's all or nothing.

Comment: thank you for the clarification